# Using React in Web Components + CSS

Tags: reactjs, web-component

I am trying to implement `web component`s using `React`. The reason I do this, is because we are a big newspaper company and our 3rd party CMS only allows for extendability using `web component`s. So I read about a way to make a `react` component a `web component` [on the official docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/web-components.html), like so:

```
const proto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype, {
  attachedCallback: {
    value: function() {
      const mountPoint = document.createElement('span');
      this.createShadowRoot().appendChild(mountPoint);

      const name = this.getAttribute('name');
      const url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=' + encodeURIComponent(name);
      ReactDOM.render(<a href={url}>{name}</a>, mountPoint);
    }
  }
});
document.registerElement('x-search', {prototype: proto});
```

This actually does work. I created a `react app` using `create-react-app` and rewrote the `index.js` like so:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

// ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

const proto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype, {
  attachedCallback: {
    value: function() {
      const mountPoint = document.createElement('span');
      this.createShadowRoot().appendChild(mountPoint);
      ReactDOM.render(<App />, mountPoint);
    }
  }
});
document.registerElement('x-my-app', {prototype: proto});

registerServiceWorker();
```

And yes—this does actually work! However, what this does, is put my CSS in a separate file and as my web component has shadow DOM it is not styled at all. It needs to live inside the generated web component, but how do I do that?